# How to implement the generalized form of std::same_as (i.e. for more than two type parameters) that is agnostic to parameter order?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, fold-expression

#### Background

We know that the concept `std::same_as` is agnostic to order (in other words, symmetric): `std::same_as<T, U>` is equivalent to `std::same_as<U, T>` ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58509147/9171697)). In this question, I would like to implement something more general: `template <typename ... Types> concept same_are = ...` that checks whether types in the pack `Types` are equal to each other.

#### My attempt

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T, typename... Others>
concept same_with_others = (... && std::same_as<T, Others>);

template <typename... Types>
concept are_same = (... && same_with_others<Types, Types...>);

template< class T, class U> requires are_same<T, U>
void foo(T a, U b) {
    std::cout << "Not integral" << std::endl;
}

// Note the order <U, T> is intentional
template< class T, class U> requires (are_same<U, T> && std::integral<T>)
void foo(T a, U b) {
    std::cout << "Integral" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    foo(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

(My intention here is to enumerate over every possible ordered pair of types in the pack)

Unfortunately, this code [would not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/-_0rLe), with the compiler complaining that the call to `foo(int, int)` is ambiguous. I believe that it considers `are_same<U, T>` and `are_same<T, U>` as not equivalent. I would like to know why the code fails how I can fix it (so that the compiler treats them as equivalent)?

Comment: My gut tells me it's gonna need a helper that executes `same_with_others` in every possible permutation of the types.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand you correctly. You want to check if _all_ types of `... Types` are the same? Maybe [std::conjunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) can help you. There is an example on the bottom of the page thats looks similiar to your approach.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica But I have already enumerated every possible ordered pair of types in the pack. Isn't that enough? Or compilers cannot determine the equivalence of folds without any concrete types?

Comment: @churill I mean to implement this in concepts, and parameter ordering needs special care in concepts.

Comment: I'm not sure, hence it's just a gut feeling. Could be the GCC devs aren't sure either yet. Could also be they haven't implemented it fully yet.

Comment: @DanielLangr I mean to test concept subsumption relation by writing specialization using stricter constrains. (test whether `are_same<U, T>` is equivalent to `are_same<T, U>`)

Comment: `std::same_as` can only be implemented with magic (a.k.a. compiler help).  So is your proposal, I suppose.

Comment: It seems that fold expressions are not handled reasonably for constraint subsumption. This works: https://godbolt.org/z/lIjbH0, but this doesn't: https://godbolt.org/z/qIR4vH. Please submit a PR.

Comment: @metalfox: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Constraint_normalization, it seems expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, with this concept:

```
template <typename T, typename... Others>
concept are_same = (... && std::same_as<T, Others>);
```

Is that the normalized form of this concept is... exactly that. We can't "unfold" this (there's nothing to do), and the current rules don't normalize through "parts" of a concept.

In other words, what you need for this to work is for your concept to normalize into:

```
... && (same-as-impl<T, U> && same-as-impl<U, T>)
```

into:

```
... && (is_same_v<T, U> && is_same_v<U, T>)
```

And consider one fold-expression `&&` constraint to subsume another fold-expression constraint `&&` if its underlying constraint subsumes the other's underlying constraint. If we had that rule, that would make your example work.

It may be possible to add this in the future - but the concern around the subsumption rules is that we do not want to require compilers to go all out and implement a full SAT solver to check constraint subsumption. This one doesn't seem like it makes it that much more complicated (we'd really just add the `&&` and `||` rules through fold-expressions), but I really have no idea.

Note however that even if we had this kind of fold-expression subsumption, `are_same<T, U>` would still not subsume `std::same_as<T, U>`. It would only subsume `are_same<U, T>`. I am not sure if this would even be possible.

Comment: It is surprising to me that [this](https://godbolt.org/z/35YJAa) doesn't work. It is reasonable that only concepts can be subsumed. However, in my opinion, `(... && C<T>)` not subsuming the *concept* `C<T>` would surprise a lot of users.

Comment: @metalfox: From my reading of normalization, your example should be fine (using constraint explicitly works though [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Z2-Wkh)).

Comment: @Jarod42 What you wrote and what metalfox wrote are not the same thing - the difference is what metalfox is talking about.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, that works because [concepts participate in constraint subsumption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062387), and you have materialized the fold expression (involving concepts) into a single concept. Unfortunately, as you stated in your answer, fold expressions are not normalized into the concepts they are made of. This doesn't work either: https://godbolt.org/z/pjmKxR

Comment: I might have misunderstood [Constraint_normalization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Constraint_normalization) then :-/ I understand `((fold1<Ts> && ...) && (fold2<Ts> &&...))` as *conjunction* of `(fold1<Ts> && ...)` and `(fold2<Ts> && ...)` whereas it is atomic.

Comment: @Jarod42 No, that's right. It is a conjunction. It's just that `(C<Ts> && ...)` is atomic, so writing `(C<Ts> && ...)` in two different places don't subsume each other. On the other hand, writing one `D<Ts...>` does.

Comment: Oh, I found the part I miss *"Only concepts can be subsumed"* from your link, which is from the part I probably misunderstand *"Two atomic constraints are considered identical if they are formed from the same expression at the source level and their parameter mappings are equivalent."*. Not yet understood `BadMeowableCat` from wording rules :-/

Answer (score 6):

From [cppreference.com Constraint_normalization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Constraint_normalization)

> The normal form of any other expression E is the atomic constraint whose expression is E and whose parameter mapping is the identity mapping. This includes all fold expressions, even those folding over the && or || operators.

So

```
template <typename... Types>
concept are_same = (... && same_with_others<Types, Types...>);
```

is "atomic".

So indeed `are_same<U, T>` and `are_same<T, U>` are not equivalent.

I don't see how to implement it :-(

Answer (score -1):

churill is right .Using std::conjunction_v might be helpful.

```
   template <typename T,typename... Types>
   concept are_same = std::conjunction_v<std::same_as<T,Types>...>;
```