# Difference between std::same_as and std::is_same

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

I was reading through the documentation of [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) and it looks like it just forwards to `std::is_same_v`. cppreference has the following example implementation:

```cpp
namespace detail {
    template< class T, class U >
    concept SameHelper = std::is_same_v<T, U>;
}
 
template< class T, class U >
concept same_as = detail::SameHelper<T, U> && detail::SameHelper<U, T>;
```

Why is the `&&` even necessary if `std::is_same_v` is commutative? And if `std::same_as` has identical semantics, what do I need it for? I can also use `std::is_same_v` as a constraint like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void test(T x) requires std::is_same_v<T, int> {}
```

Comment: The question is answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509147/why-does-same-as-concept-check-type-equality-twice

If you want to understand more about concepts, check this blog:
https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2020/05/07/ordering-by-constraints/