# How to understand the partial ordering by constraints

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The partial ordering rules of constraints are defined as:
[[temp.constr.order#1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.order#1)

> A constraint P subsumes a constraint Q if and only if, for every disjunctive clause P<sub>i</sub> in the disjunctive normal form of P, P<sub>i</sub> subsumes every conjunctive clause Q<sub>j</sub> in the conjunctive normal form of Q, where
>
> > - a disjunctive clause P<sub>i</sub> subsumes a conjunctive clause Q<sub>j</sub> if and only if there exists an atomic constraint P<sub>ia</sub> in P<sub>i</sub> for which there exists an atomic constraint Q<sub>jb</sub> in Q<sub>j</sub> such that P<sub>ia</sub> subsumes Q<sub>jb</sub>, and
> > - an atomic constraint A subsumes another atomic constraint B if and only if A and B are identical using the rules described in [temp.constr.atomic].

I don't know how to get the disjunctive and conjunctive normal forms of a given constraint. Moreover, I have some confusion about the second bullet.

#### Question 1:

Given a constraint named P with the form `A ∧ B` and another constraint named Q with the form `A` where `A` and `B` are both atomic constraints.  For constraint  `P` what's the disjunctive normal form of it? Whereas, what's the conjunctive and disjunctive normal form of `Q`?

#### Question 2:

Is that P<sub>i</sub> and Q<sub>j</sub> is taken from the clauses of the corresponding positions of their disjunctive /conjunctive normal form?  Especially, how to understand the sentence if and only if there exists an atomic constraint P<sub>ia</sub> in P<sub>i</sub> for which there exists an atomic constraint Q<sub>jb</sub> in Q<sub>j</sub> such that P<sub>ia</sub> subsumes Q<sub>jb</sub>? How to interpret the case that `Qi` has an extra atomic constraint that Pi does not have? Does that `P` subsumes `Q`? Could you give an exposition process to interpret why does `A ∧ B` subsume `A`?

Comment: please add link for the quote.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Added that.

Comment: [Somewhat related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66028092/4573247).

Comment: @dfrib Yeah, I have found a wonderful [online logic calculator](http://melihovv.ru/LogicCalculator/), that helps me to transform a formula to its CNF or DNF in order to analyze the relevant rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `A ∧ B` and `A` are already in disjunctive normal form *and* conjunctive normal form.

In this case, there is one disjunctive clause in `P`, and one conjunctive clause in `Q`.

You then check if any subclause of `P0` (`A ∧ B`) subsumes any subclause of `Q0` (`A`), which it does (`A` subsumes `A`).

Comment: How to get DNF or CNF? If `P0(A)` while `Q0(A V B)`, Does that P0 subsume Q0?

Comment: You have to substitute clauses until you have a disjunction of conjunctions (for dnf) or a conjunction of disjunctions (for cnf). `((a ^ b) v c) ^ d` is an example of something you'd have to mess with, as is `!(a ^ b)`

Comment: It may be clearer if I overbracket your example: `P = ((A ∧ B))`; `P0 = (A ∧ B)`; `P00 = A`, `P01 = B`. `Q = ((A))`; `Q0 = (A)`; `Q00 = A`.

Comment: For the second bullet, Does that mean merely exists Pia that can identity to Qib, then Pi will subsume Qi? Such as `P0(A)` and Q0(A V B)? P0 will subsume Q0?

Comment: Yes, because `P00` subsumes `Q00`

Comment: Isn't `A V B` a disjunction clause of Q where its CNF were  `(A V B) ∧ B`? That is Q0 would be `A V B` while P0 were `A`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229769/discussion-between-caleth-and-jack-x).