# How to implement heterogenous lookup aka specialize a template class minimizing code repetition

Tags: c++, templates, containers, c++20, template-specialization

Consider a class like this (omitting details):

```cpp
template<typename K, typename V>
class my_flat_map
{
    // A lot of member functions taking a const ref to key
    auto find(K const& key) { /*...*/ }
    auto contains(K const& key) { /*...*/ }
    auto insert_or_assign(K const& key, V const& val) { /*...*/ }
    auto insert_if_missing(K const& key, V const& val) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
};
```

When instantiating the template with a string-like key type
I'd like to have all those member functions just accepting
the corresponding string_view instead of a const reference
to the actual key type.
I know that I can obtain this with a partial specialization
for each possible string class:

```cpp
template<typename V>
class my_flat_map<std::u32string,V>
{
    auto find(std::u32string_view key) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
};

template<typename V>
class my_flat_map<std::u16string,V>
{
    auto find(std::u16string_view key) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
};

template<typename V>
class my_flat_map<std::u8string,V>
{
    auto find(std::u8string_view key) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
};

template<typename V>
class my_flat_map<other::esotic_string,V>
{
    auto find(other::esotic_string_view key) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
};

// ...
```

The bodies of all the member functions are exactly the same,
the only change is the signature.
Is there a mechanism to express this without repeating all
the code?

Comment: You can write a `concept` which accepts all your string types and write your specialization only once.

Comment: @user12002570 you cannot use `if constexpr` at class scope. You can only use it at block scope (e.g. inside a function), but that won't let you change the parameter types in itself.

Comment: @JanSchultke Yes, I know that. I was suggesting that inside the function they can use `constexpr if` but seeing that the function parameter depends upon it, using `if constexpr` wouldn't be possible for the reason you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Approach A

You could add an alias to your class:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

// for all non-string types, we fall back to const T&
template <typename T>
struct key_view { using type = const T&; };

// For any specialization of std::basic_string, we use the
// corresponding std::basic_string_view.
// For example, key_view<std::string>::type = std::string_view
template <typename Char, typename Traits, typename Alloc>
struct key_view<std::basic_string<Char, Traits, Alloc>> {
    using type = std::basic_string_view<Char, Traits>;
};

// If the key is already a std::basic_string_view, we just use that as the type.
template <typename Char, typename Traits>
struct key_view<std::basic_string_view<Char, Traits>> {
    using type = std::basic_string_view<Char, Traits>;
};

template<typename K, typename V>
struct my_flat_map
{
    // No major change to the flat_map needed, we just use this alias
    using key_view = key_view<K>::type;

    auto find(key_view key) { /*...*/ }
    auto contains(key_view key) { /*...*/ }
    auto insert_or_assign(key_view key, V const& val) { /*...*/ }
    auto insert_if_missing(key_view key, V const& val) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
};
```

Without any further changes to `my_flat_map`, you can add more partial specializations of `key_view` to handle more string-like types (perhaps Qt or boost strings).

#### Further Notes

Also note that using `key_view` in `insert_` functions makes no sense. When inserting, the standard library usually uses two overloads for `K&&` and `const K&`. You can't insert a view anyway, so keep it:

```cpp
auto insert_or_assign(K const& key, V const& val) { /*...*/ }
auto insert_or_assign(K && key, V const& val) { /*...*/ }
auto insert_or_assign(K const& key, V && val) { /*...*/ }
auto insert_or_assign(K && key, V && val) { /*...*/ }
```

To avoid repetition, you can use a function template instead. Look into `std::map::try_emplace` for design inspiration:

```cpp
template <typename Key, typename... Args>
auto try_emplace_or_assign(K && key, Args && ...args) { /*...*/ }
```

### Approach B

You can simply turn some operations into templates to generally support heterogeneous lookup, not just in special cases like `std::string_view`:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <typename T, typename U>
concept equality_with_impl = requires (const T& a, const U& b) {
    { a == b } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
concept equality_with = equality_with_impl<T, U> && equality_with_impl<U, T>;

template<typename K, typename V>
struct my_flat_map
{
    template <equality_with<K> T, typename Equal = std::ranges::equal_to>
    auto find(const T& key, Equal equal = {}) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
};
```

Now, if the user calls `my_flat_map<std::string, ...>::find` with a `const char*`, `std::string`, or `std::string_view`, it would always work because `std::string` has a `==` operator for these.

The user can also provide a custom `Equal` function object in case there is no appropriate `==`.

---

*Note: if you're wondering why both `equality_with` and `equality_with_impl` are necessary, refer to: [Why does same_as concept check type equality twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58509147/5740428)*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map one type, `K`, to another, the argument to `find`, you can write a trait and specialze it:

```
template <typename K>
struct find_arg;

template <typename K>
using find_arg_t = typename find_arg::type;

// specialize for each type:
template <> struct find_arg<std::u16string> {
     using type = std::u16string_view;
};
// ...
```

However, `std::u16string` is just an alias for `std::basic_string<char16_t>` just as `std::u16string_view` is an alias for `std::basic_string_view<char16_t>`. Further, `std::basic_string::CharT` is the character type of the string. Hence, you can save all the above boilerplate and use `std::basic_string_view< typename K::CharT>`. And if `other::esotic_string` does not have a `CharT` (it should) you can fall back to the above that uses `CharT` when available and your custom specialization otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You specialize the class by checking whether `basic_string_view` can be constructed with the object of type `const K`:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class my_flat_map
{
  // A lot of member functions taking a const ref to key
  auto find(K const& key) { /*...*/ }
  auto contains(K const& key) { /*...*/ }
  auto insert_or_assign(K const& key, V const& val) { /*...*/ }
  auto insert_if_missing(K const& key, V const& val) { /*...*/ }
  // ...
};

template<typename K, typename V>
  requires requires (const K& key) { 
    std::basic_string_view{key}; 
  }
class my_flat_map<K, V>
{
  using string_view_type = decltype(
    std::basic_string_view{std::declval<const K&>()}
  );
  auto find(string_view_type key) { /*...*/ }
  // ...
};
```

which covers other string-like types such as `const char*` or `std::span<char8_t>`.

Comment: An unfortunate issue is that `my_flat_map<const char*, ...>` would have `string_view_type = std::string_view`. However, this would be nonsensical because `std::string_view` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated and `const char*` is assumed to be, so the container would become unusable. (At least insertion wouldn't be possible, though `find` can still be implemented)